# How to replace string of digits with a padded version of that string in regular expression substitution?

Tags: .net, regex, padding

I've got a string of digits that is either 4 or 5 digits long and it needs to be padded with "0" till it's 6 digits long. Is this possible? I'm using .Net framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression to perform this operation. You can use [`string.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx):

```
s = s.PadLeft(6, '0');
```

If you need to use regular expression (perhaps because you are performing some more complex replacement of which this is just a small part) then you can use a [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) in combination with the above technique:

```
string s = "foo <12423> bar";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"<(\d+)>", match => match.Groups[1].Value.PadLeft(6, '0'));
```

Result:

```
foo 012423 bar
```

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid it wasn't possible.